# Node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click')) no longer triggers anchor since Chrome v53

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I had the following code in a Chrome only web application, which has been working fine for a long while, when the dispatch happened then the attached listener was fired and the anchor was triggered and followed.

```js
const id = document.getElementById('me');
id.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked', e), false);
const cancelled = !id.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));
if (cancelled) {
  console.log("canceled");
} else {
  console.log("not canceled");
}
```

```html
<a id="me" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">xxx</a>
```

But then as of Chrome V53, it is no longer working, it will fire an attached event but no longer triggers and follows the anchor?

I've changed the code, and this method still works.

```js
const id = document.getElementById('me');
id.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked', e), false);
const evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
const cancelled = !id.dispatchEvent(evt);
if (cancelled) {
  console.log("canceled");
} else {
  console.log("not canceled");
}
```

```html
<a id="me" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">xxx</a>
```

I tried the snippets in FireFox v48 and had the same result, though the application is never run in FireFox.

Has some specification changed, I've tried to search for an answer but haven't been able to find the reason?

Comment: I'm not seeing a change specific to M53 related to this, are you sure it wasn't M52, M51, or similar?

Comment: It could have been, I'm not sure what the previous version was before the update and assumed that it was v52 but it could have been prior to that. All I am sure of is that it was working for a long time, even if it was not the correct code and behaviour.

Comment: Dispatching Untrusted events was switched off in M53 (there was a warning in the Console. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 and https://crbug.com/520519 (this affects my app too on Chrome on Android and in Device emulation in DevTools - can't open dropdown SELECTs) (it was already off in IE and FF, Chrome decided to also block it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`click` is a `MouseEvent`, not a `CustomEvent`. If you use `new MouseEvent('click')`, it works.

Presumably a bugfix, since `CustomEvent` shouldn't have triggered the link in the first place.

Using `new MouseEvent` instead of `new CustomEvent`:

```js
const id = document.getElementById('me');
id.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked', e), false);
const cancelled = !id.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
if (cancelled) {
  console.log("canceled");
} else {
  console.log("not canceled");
}
```

```html
<a id="me" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">xxx</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that works perfectly. But yes, it must have been a recent bugfix (withing the last coupe of versions). I will accept as soon as the timer expires.